# how to implement ESAPI in zend framework 1?

Tags: security, validation, zend-framework, xss, zend-form

currently am working a project using zend framework 1, i need to implement ESAPI to do xss validations. I googled for some good tutorials but had no luck. Can any one help me on this to find some good tutorials on net?

many thanks in advance!!

-kumar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just address XSS you donot need ESAPI. Do a strict validation on each user input (form fields) using regular expressions and encode the output before the display.

ESAPI will give you complete security controls that an enterprise application should have.
There is java implementation exist. I am not sure which language Zend supports to write the form handlers.Check the .Net version of ESAPI if it works with Zend.